# DBMI-SQLite driver error: Error in sqlite3_prepare(): near ".": syntax error in db.execute command

Tags: sqlite

I try to make a query with inner join from grass gis (but in that community this question was concerned as offtopic, so it seems to concern only SQL lite):

```
db.execute sql="UPDATE A SET A.next2=B.next_stream 
                FROM stream_order2 AS A 
                INNER JOIN stream_order2 AS B ON A.factor=B.stream"
```

I have to do this because I would like to set values of next2 as values of next stream from table corresponding to stream numbers equal to factor value.
db.execute throws an error.

Then I updated the command and removed A. statement. Now the error is:

```
Error in sqlite3_prepare():
 near "FROM": syntax error
```

I tried to remove A. after ON, but it doesn't help, I don't think it's the issue.

Comment: What SQLite version are you using because `update from` syntax is supported from  v3.33 version ?

Comment: I can't find exactly what version it is, but as in throws sqlite3 error, seem to be 3 and up. Grass I have is 7.8.7. version. Developers may write somewhere about sql version, but I can't find it.

Comment: Can I run it from bash somehow?

Comment: If by bash you mean cli such as terminal ? If so yes and the first thing you should see would be something like `SQLite version 3.28.0 2019-04-15 14:49:49`

Comment: I have SQLite version 3.27.2 2019-02-25 16:06:06

Comment: @NikolayYasinskiy See first comment: *What SQLite version are you using because update from syntax is supported from v3.33 version ?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have SQLite version 3.27.2 2019-02-25 16:06:06

[UPDATE FROM](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html#upfrom) is supported beginning in SQLite version 3.33.0 (2020-08-14).

You can get around this by using a correlated subquery and having suitable indexes ,

```
UPDATE stream_order2
SET next2 = (SELECT B.next_stream
             FROM stream_order2 B
             WHERE B.stream=stream_order2.factor )
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
              FROM stream_order2 B
              WHERE B.stream=stream_order2.factor)
```

See example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/irh5_5yO)

Comment: It works. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I have forgotten. I am aware