# In GRASS GIS db.execute IN statement works, but NOT IN doesn't

Tags: sqlite

Here is my command for GRASS GIS database (SQL Lite driver used):

```
db.execute sql="UPDATE streams_order SET factor=next_stream WHERE number IS NOT NULL AND next_stream IN (SELECT number FROM streams_order)"
```

But.. I want

```
db.execute sql="UPDATE streams_order SET factor=next_stream WHERE number IS NOT NULL AND next_stream NOT IN (SELECT number FROM streams_order)"
```

And result should be:

```
+---------+--------------+--------+---------+
| stream  |  next_stream   factor |  number |
+-------------------------------------------+
  370           -1           
  372           370         370       372
  374           440         
  376           372                   376
  380           374         374       380
.............................................
```

it doesn't work without any error: "factor" column is empty after running the command. If I put IN it works well.
Column types are all INT.

Sandbox with real data is here https://dbfiddle.uk/zg8_xJUz

Comment: I can't find SQL Lite tag

Comment: You mean this update?

Comment: I am not sure if 5 tip is useful here, as it is not about query, but about execute a grass internal database command.

Comment: I have it all in one database sqllite.db... Is it because of grass particularities

Comment: Sorry. I can export following formats:
AmigoCloud, BAG, BNA, CSV, Carto, Cloudant, CouchDB, DGN, DXF, ESRI_Shapefile, Elasticsearch, FITS, FlatGeobuf, GML, GMLAS, GPKG, GPSBabel, GPSTrackMaker, GPX, GeoJSON, GeoJSONSeq, GeoRSS, Geoconcept, Interlis_1, Interlis_2, JML, JP2OpenJPEG, KML, LIBKML, MBTiles, MSSQLSpatial, MVT, MapInfo_File, MapML, Memory, MySQL, NGW, ODBC, ODS, OGR_GMT, PCIDSK, PDF, PDS4, PGDUMP, PostgreSQL, S57, SQLite, Selafin, TIGER, VDV, VICAR, WAsP, XLSX, netCDF

Comment: But it's logical, if IN is supported, so NOT IN should be also supported.

Comment: I used your example and created a sandbox, that we can use for both questions.

https://dbfiddle.uk/mj1TdUS_

Kindly look there and you'll see, that if I put NOT IN statement nothing changes, but if IN - it calculates correctly. factor and factor2 are calculated correctly with Excel formulae. factor_new and factor2_new are for sqllite experiments. Data is real. Queries for second question I haven't corrected yet, so they give errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is related to the presence on NULL values in the `number` column.

NOT IN always fails when the list has NULL values because NULL comparisons cannot be true or false.

More precisely, in SQL logic NULL doesn't mean "empty", it means "undetermined".
A comparison `val = NULL` will always result NULL, even if val is also NULL. This is why, to check if something is NULL, we need to use the special operator `IS NULL`.

The expression `val IN ('A', NULL)` will be translated as `val='A' OR val=NULL`.

If val is equal to 'A' that will become `TRUE OR NULL`, which evaluates to `TRUE`. (and NOT IN evaluates to `FALSE`).
But if val is equal to 'B' that expression becomes `FALSE OR NULL`, which evaluates to `NULL` (and NOT IN is still `NULL`).

So, in a list with null elements, `val IN (...)` will evaluates to TRUE if one of the not null element equals to val, and NULL otherwise, while `val NOT IN (...)` will evaluate to FALSE if one of the not null elements equals to val and NULL otherwise, but it will never evaluates to TRUE, so your update will never fire.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924431/sql-not-in-subquery-is-not-working-as-expected).

Workaround:

```
UPDATE streams_order SET factor=next_stream 
WHERE number IS NOT NULL AND 
      next_stream NOT IN (SELECT number FROM streams_order WHERE number IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: I like your solution more, it's elegant, and you gave good explanations. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> if IN is supported, so NOT IN should be also supported

If something is unsupported you will be facing with some error , like you have in your previous question [DBMI-SQLite driver error: Error in sqlite3_prepare(): near ".": syntax error in db.execute command](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/330897/dbmi-sqlite-driver-error-error-in-sqlite3-prepare-near-syntax-error-in).

To debug the issue before running the update statement , run a select.

If I run the same update query transformed in select statement you will see that no record is returned.

```
select factor2_new,next_stream,number 
from stream_order
WHERE number IS NOT NULL AND next_stream NOT IN (SELECT number FROM stream_order)
```

Now the problem stands in the query.

I would suggest using `not exists` rather than `not in` , see [SQL "select where not in subquery" returns no results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406215/sql-select-where-not-in-subquery-returns-no-results) for the differences between exists and in.

Change your select query to,

```
SELECT  *
FROM  stream_order
WHERE number IS NOT NULL 
AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT  NULL
                 FROM    stream_order so
                 WHERE   so.number = stream_order.next_stream )
```

Result,

```
stream  next_stream factor  factor2 next_stream2    number  factor_new  factor2_new next2
  111      222      null       -1       -1           333        null    null    null
  370      -1       null       -1       -1           370        null    null    null
  398      394      null       394      394          398        null    null    null
  404      402      null       402      402          404        null    null    null
  420      416      null       416      416          420        null    null    null
  458      454      null       454      454          458        null    null    null
```

Update query,

```
UPDATE stream_order
SET factor2_new=next_stream 
WHERE number IS NOT NULL 
AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT  NULL
                 FROM    stream_order so
                 WHERE   so.number = stream_order.next_stream )
```

See [example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/psimKzOm)

Comment: I works well too.